# FFMPEG swscale 1920x1080 UYVY422 down to odd width produces incorrect colors

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv, swscale

I am using libswscale (from FFMPEG) to scale a 1920x1080 UYVY422 image to a size that is decided programmatically, based on what size window we are rendering to.

When resizing my "canvas", I noticed that the color of the image would change back and forth between normal and invalid (incorrect colors).

After analyzing the dimensions at which the color would be invalid, I noticed that the image always appeared to be correct when the width is an even number of pixels.

```
1920x1080 scaled to 867x488
doesn't work

1920x1080 scaled to 1016x572
works

19280x1080 scaled to 975x548
doesn't work

19280x1080 scaled to 962x541
works
```

I have since updated my code to always scale to an even width.

```
if ((targetSize.cx % 2) != 0)
{
    targetSize.cx = targetSize.cx - 1;
}
```

It works with this code. However, I still don't understand why it does this. If I scale an image that is originally and odd width, do I have to ensure my width is also odd? I'd like to understand this.

Comment: It is typical for 4:2:2 images to have even width because U and V planes are subsampled, and have one value for two neighboring pixels. I am not sure at what stage you have incorrect data interpretation for odd-width 4:2:2 YUV image, but simply because of this subsampling you are normally interested in avoiding odd resolutions.

Comment: @RomanR, should I avoid odd heights also? 962x541 works, but should I still change it to 962x540?

Comment: Well, not for 4:2:2 because all rows are independent with 4:2:2. However yes, you'd better avoid that with 4:2:0 because there is vertical subsampling there as well. Figures [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should give you idea about subsampling (and you definitely will find many other tutorials on this as well - e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JYZDnenaGc)). With some formats you might need to have stricter alignment (width e.g. divisible by 4).